Finding out Neighbors using SQL/R Loops
I have the following dataframe in R:
friendships <- structure(list(person = c("person3", "person10", "person2", "person6", 
                                         "person4", "person6", "person10", "person5", "person3", "person9", 
                                         "person9", "person9", "person3", "person8", "person10", "person7", 
                                         "person10"), 
                              friend = c("person9", "person4", "person1", "person7", 
                                         "person10", "person7", "person9", "person10", "person7", "person5", 
                                         "person7", "person5", "person6", "person9", "person2", "person5", 
                                         "person8")), 
                         row.names = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L), 
                         class = "data.frame")


For person10, I want to find out the names and numbers of neighbors of degree=2.
In igraph, I can do it like this:
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(friendships, directed = FALSE)

#names of neighbors at degree=2
> ego(g, 2, "person10")

[[1]]
+ 9/10 vertices, named, from 6632700:
[1] person10 person2  person4  person5  person9  person8  person1  person7  person3 

#number of neighbors at degree=2

 > length(unlist(ego(g, 2, "person10")))
[1] 9

My Question: Now, I want to do this only using SQL code and R functions/loops (i.e. no igraph).
Here is my attempt to do this:
library(sqldf)

#first locate neighbors of person10
friends <- sqldf("SELECT friend FROM friendships WHERE person = 'person10'")

# nxt, initialize the list of friends with degree 2
friends_degree2 <- friends

From here, I tried to write a loop:
    while (TRUE) {
        new_friends <- sqldf(paste0("SELECT friend FROM friendships WHERE person IN ('", paste(friends$friend, collapse="','"), "')"))
        
        new_friends <- unique(new_friends)
        
        if (all(new_friends$friend %in% friends_degree2$friend)) {
            break
        }
      
        friends_degree2 <- unique(rbind(friends_degree2, new_friends))
        
        friends <- new_friends
    }

From here, we can check the answers:

    > print(nrow(friends_degree2))
    [1] 8
    > 
    > print(friends_degree2)
         friend
    1   person4
    2   person9
    3   person2
    4   person8
    11  person1
    21 person10
    31  person5
    41  person7

However, person3 is not included in this list?
Can someone please show me how to fix this?

You can use ``SELECT friend FROM friendships WHERE person = 'person10' union SELECT person FROM friendships WHERE friend = 'person10' " to take booth sides of friendships.

@ ValNik: thank you so much for your reply! If you have time, can you please write an answer with this idea? thank you so much!

The code in the question using ego is giving the degree 1 and 2 neighbors.  If that is what you want then compute the degree 1 neighbors and using those find the degree 2 neighbors and then return both or if you just want the degree 2 neighbors then remove union select f from deg1 in the code below.
library(sqldf)
sqldf("with deg1 as (
   select friend f from friendships where person = 'person10'
   union
   select person f from friendships where friend = 'person10'
  )
  select friend f from friendships where person in (select f from deg1)
  union 
  select person f from friendships where friend in (select f from deg1)
  union select f from deg1"
)
##          f
## 1  person1
## 2 person10
## 3  person2
## 4  person3
## 5  person4
## 6  person5
## 7  person7
## 8  person8
## 9  person9

Here is a variation that factors out the double lookup into a new table sym.  If you want just degree 2 then remove the last line that begins with union and replace the last select with select distinct.
sqldf("with
  sym as (
    select * from friendships
    union
    select friend as person, person as friend from friendships
  ),
  deg1 as (
    select friend f from sym where person = 'person10'
  )
  select friend f from  sym where person in (select f from deg1)
  union select f from deg1"
)
##          f
## 1  person1
## 2 person10
## 3  person2
## 4  person3
## 5  person4
## 6  person5
## 7  person7
## 8  person8
## 9  person9


Your code is treating the network as a directed graph, but you are searching the neighbors in the undirected sense. That's is the reason you don't have person3 in the degree of 2 neighbors of person10, since the your neighborhood is limited to the "outwards" manner, rather than "outwards" + "inwards".

With base R, you can use for loop like below
f <- function(friendships, v = "person10", deg = 2) {
    key <- v
    for (i in 1:deg) {
        key <- unique(unlist(subset(friendships, person %in% key | friend %in% key)))
    }
    key
}

so you will obtain, for example
> f(friendships, "person1")
[1] "person2"  "person10" "person1"

> f(friendships, "person3")
[1] "person3"  "person6"  "person10" "person9"  "person8"  "person7"  "person5"

> f(friendships, "person10")
[1] "person3"  "person10" "person2"  "person4"  "person5"  "person9"  "person8"
[8] "person7"  "person1"


thank you so much for your answer! Is it possible to write your answer such that it contains SQL code?

@stats_noob sorry that I don't know SQL

@ThomasIsCoding, I suggest your answer here should really be over there, where the OP is asking for what you've done here. (This question did seem to be clear on the need for SQL.)

@r2evans aha, probably you are right. I just saw the title and understood it as "SQL or R loops".

The issue here is the direction of the edges. In your dataframe, the edges are directed from person to friend, but not from friend back to person. In igraph this is managed using directed=FALSE.
Person 3 has three edges in your graph, but they are all "out" edges. Person 3 does not appear in the second vector of your list. To make your graph undirected, you have to include a reverse edge for each pair. This may be achieved as:
friendships <- rbind(friendships, friendships[,c(2,1)])

The above code just adds a set of reversed edges, from each of your out-nodes to each of your in-nodes

Your code looks like a mix of R and Python. In R it's FALSE not False and friendships[:,c(2,1)] is a syntax error. I think you want friendships[,c(2,1)]

@user160623: thank you so much for your answer! Can you write a full answer if you have time?
